# Error de importación de archivos

Tags: python-3.x, vscode

Estoy iniciando Python en vscode, pero cuando puedo importar múltiples herencias, vscode me marca un error y no puedo resolver el error, gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

1- Descargar este archivo: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

2- Ejecutar en el cmd: `python get-pip.py` (get-pip.py es el archivo que te has descargado)

3- Ejecutar en el cmd: `python`

4- Una vez estés dentro del python debes ejecutar el instalador: `pip install colour`

Cierras y ejecutas de nuevo el editor. A continuación no deberías tener problemas.

Espero que te sirva :)